Reactive extension method works in assembly targeting net48 but throws `MissingMethodException` targeting netstandard2.0
I have an extension method defined in a class library (call it My.Extensions.Reactive):
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a sequence that is generated by comparing each of an underlying Observable's emitted values to the value which was emitted first.
    /// The first item emitted by this Observable is the result of comparing the first item to itself.
    /// </summary>
    public static IObservable<TResult> RelativeToFirst<TValue, TResult>(this IObservable<TValue> observable, Func<TValue, TValue, TResult> selector)
    {
        // .Publish ensures the underlying stream is not disposed until this stream is unsubscribed.
        return observable.Publish(published => published.Take(1)
            .CombineLatest(published)
            .Select(((TValue First, TValue Current) combined) => selector(combined.First, combined.Current)));
    }
}

I have a unit test case defined in an xUnit project which targets .NET Framework 4.8.
public class ObservableExtensionsTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task RelativeToFirst()
    {
        var input = Observable.Range(5, 10);

        var expected = Observable.Range(0, 10);

        var result = input.RelativeToFirst((initial, current) => current - initial);

        Assert.Equal(await expected.ToArray(), await result.ToArray());
    }
}

If My.Extensions.Reactive.csproj targets net48, the unit test passes.
I want the My.Extensions.Reactive library to target netstandard2.0, so that I can use it in projects that target newer .NET versions, while still supporting .NET 4.8. However, when I change its TargetFramework to netstandard2.0 and reinstall the System.Reactive 6.0.1 NuGet packages, the unit test which still targets net48 fails, throwing the following xUnit output:
System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 'System.IObservable`1<System.ValueTuple`2<!!0,!!1>> System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableEx.CombineLatest(System.IObservable`1<!!0>, System.IObservable`1<!!1>)'.
   at My.Extensions.Reactive.ObservableExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`2.<RelativeToFirst>b__0(IObservable`1 published)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Multicast`3._.Run(Multicast`3 parent)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.AsyncSubject`1.GetResult()
   at My.Extensions.Reactive_Test.ObservableExtensionsTests.<RelativeToFirst>d__0.MoveNext() in redacted\ObservableExtensionsTests.cs:line 19
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xunit.Sdk.TestInvoker`1.<>c__DisplayClass47_0.<<InvokeTestMethodAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/TestInvoker.cs:line 259
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExecutionTimer.<AggregateAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/ExecutionTimer.cs:line 48
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAggregator.<RunAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in /_/src/xunit.core/Sdk/ExceptionAggregator.cs:line 90

Why is this happening? The System.Reactive NuGet package includes specific targeting information for netstandard2.0, among other options, and .NET Framework 4.8 projects are supposed to be able to take dependencies on .NET Standard 2.0 libraries, right?
The "missing" System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableEx.CombineLatest() method is trivial to navigate to using Visual Studio's "Go To Definition". The unit test error is occurring at runtime error rather than compile-time. The test project does not directly reference the System.Reactive NuGet package but the required DLL does seem to be present in the test project's bin\x64 folder.

